# Задать Source для WebBrowser в WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Есть приложение C# WPF в котором присутствует 2 `WPF Window` на одной несколько кнопок и  `WebBrowser` на другой. При щелчке по одной из кнопок на открывается второе окно а  `WebBrowser` отображает некоторую страницу. Каждый раз страница может быть другой. Код обработчик кнопок :

```
      ActiveInfo active = new ActiveInfo();
      active.URI = YahooFinans.httpString(YahooFinans.Tikker(row.Type));
      active.Show();
```

Окно с браузером :

```
public partial class ActiveInfo : Window
{
    public ActiveInfo()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public string URI { get; set; }
}
```

И `XAML` разметка :

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"/>
</Window.DataContext>

<Grid>
    <WebBrowser Source="{Binding URI}">  !!!
    </WebBrowser>
</Grid>
```

И именно на разметке падает исключение : `System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException`

> Дополнительные сведения: "Binding" нельзя задать в свойстве "Source" типа "WebBrowser". "Binding" можно задать только в параметре DependencyProperty объекта DependencyObject.

Как с этим бороться? Пробовал контекст данных вывести в отдельный класс но ошибка та же.

Comment: У меня лежит в проекте атачед свойство BindableSource на эту тему, но не используется. Попробуйте использовать http://paste.org.ru/?f89xhn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Раз у вас `MainWindow` не имплементирует INPC и `URI` — не dependency property, то смысла в привязке особого нет.

Попробуйте так:

```
public partial class ActiveInfo : Window
{
    public ActiveInfo()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public Uri URI
    {
        get => browser.Source;
        set => browser.Source = value;
    }
}
```

и XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <WebBrowser Name="browser"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: т.е. нужно просто `INPC` в `ActiveInfo` реализовать ?

Comment: @Сергей: Нет, этого недостаточно. Ещё `browser.Source` должно быть dependency property, но оно не является. С другой стороны, зачем вам привязка к собственному свойству? Проще всего реализовать так, как в ответе.

Comment: ваше решение работает , благодарю!. разобраться бы еще что такое `dependency property`.

Comment: Ну вот английская документация: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/dependency-properties-overview (есть ли русская, не знаю)